# Checking if a URL exists or not in Client Side Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

My objective is to check whether a URL is valid or not from client side. I tried the following things:
1. Tried using a ajax request using dataType as JSON. - Got the Cross-Origin Request Blocked error.
2. Tried using the JSONP as datatype. - Worked fine for some websites like google.com but it cribed for others like facebook.com

Got the error like "Refused to execute script from
[FaceBook](https://www.facebook.com/?callback=jQuery32107833494968122849_1505110738710&_=1505110738711)

```
callback=jQuery32107833494968122849_1505110738710&_=1505110738711'
```

because its MIME type

`('text/html')` is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Is there any workaround for this. I just want to make sure that the URL is valid irrespective of the content in the response.

Following is the code I wrote:

```
<html>
  <body>
     <script 

     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<script>
    function CallPageMethod() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://www.google.com/",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    alert("Success");
                },
                error: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    if (data.status === 200) {
                        alert("Finally I am done")
                    } else {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                },
            });
    }
</script>
<Button onclick="CallPageMethod()">Test URL</Button>
</body>

</html>
```

Any Suggestions or any alternative approach that I should follow to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no proper way to do this client-side, that would “work for all websites”.

Answer (score 0):

Not properly, but Most sites have a favicon.ico either from the site directly or provided from the hosting company for the site if it is a 404 image.

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico"
     onload="alert('icon loaded')">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"
     onload="alert('ajax loaded')"></script>
```

Although iframe and object do have onload events, invalid pages also trigger the event.

This would be the fastest site test I can think of ...

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
   alert("image width is " + img.naturalWidth + " not zero so site is valid");
}
img.src = "https://www.google.com/favicon.ico";
```

As for facebook, the each page uses resources from another url, iframes are blocked as well as scripts. You would need to make the request from a server to test if a page existed.

Answer (score 0):

You're best off writing a proxy on your server so:

- Client hits your server with the URL you want to check
- Your server makes the request to that URL and gets a response (or not)
- Server returns status code to the client

This way will avoid the CORS issues you're having to navigate and will allow you to set any HTTP headers you need to.